# MonoDevelop changes my code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am using MonoDevelop but every time when I hit enter of tab or space, mono develop changes my text. He add tabs or sometimes he change a word (if -> IEnumerable) or add new lines.

I am sure this has a name but I have no idea, sorry.
But can I turn it off?

Comment: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Changing-the-auto-formatting-behavior-td4649625.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools > Options > Then in the Text editor section General > Turn off code completion.